# How to return the number of values that has a specific count

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I would like to find how many occurrences of a specific value count a column contains. For example, based on the data frame below, I want to find how many values in the ID column are repeated **twice**

```
| ID       | 
| -------- | 
| 000001   |            
| 000001   | 
| 000002   | 
| 000002   | 
| 000002   | 
| 000003   | 
| 000003   |
```

The output should look something like this

```
Number of ID's repeated twice: 2
The ID's that are repeated twice are: 

| ID       | 
| -------- | 
| 000001   | 
| 000003   |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df['var'].value_counts()` to get this info. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series(['000001',
               '000001',
               '000002',
               '000002',
               '000002',
               '000003',
               '000003'])

vc = x.value_counts()
vc.index[vc == 2]
# Index(['000003', '000001'], dtype='object')
```

Beware though of potential conversion of the original data into strings for the series index though. (If that is a problem, using something like `df.groupby('x',as_index=False).size()` may be a better option.)

Comment: The second option seemed to work perfectly fine, but it returns the column within my data frame in its entirety which can be inconvenient. Isn't there a way to filter out the specific counts of 2 and display them as a data frame itself. Furthermore, is it possible to do something like this `Number of ID's repeated twice: 2`

Comment: I mean you can either assign intermediate objects and work with them, or continue to do method chaining, e.g. `df.groupby('x',as_index=False).size().query('size == 2').shape[0]` will get you your 2, `df.groupby('x',as_index=False).size().query('size == 2')['x']` will get you a series, etc. (You will need to assign the objects at some point though!)